# Laravel Eloquent: hasManyThrough Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the following classes (simplified here) in my Laravel 5.7 model:

VEHICLE.PHP

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{

    public function journeys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Journey');
    }

}
```

JOURNEY PHP

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Journey extends Model
{

    public function vehicle()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Vehicle');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

USER.PHP

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{  

    public function journeys()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Journey');
    }
}
```

I have an intermediate table (journey_user) between users and journeys (see schema attached).

[image]

I can easily get all journeys made by a particular user. But **how can I get all vehicles used by a particular user?** The standard hasManyThrough method does not appear to work because of the Many to Many relationship between users and journeys.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like the Vehicle is a property of the Journey -- so your best bet is to go through that relationship. If you want an easy-access method to the Vehicles used by the User throughout his Journeys then I'd create some sort of Repository or Service for that logic ... _not_ within the User model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this out. However, it should be possible to get all `vehicles` by looping through all the `user`'s `journeys`, creating an array of vehicles and return this as a `collection`.

This can be added to your `User.php` model controller:

```
/**
 * Get all vehicles which user has used
 *
 */
public function vehicles()
{
    $vehicles = [];

    $this->journeys()
        ->each(function ($journey, $key) use (&$vehicles) {
            $vehicles[] = $journey->vehicle;
        });

    return collect($vehicles);
}
```

Here, we create an empty array. Then we loop through all the journeys of the users (passing the `$vehicles` array as a reference to update it).

We use the `each()` collection method to loop through each `journey`. We create a new entry to the `$vehicles` array, adding the `vehicle`.

Finally, we return all `vehicles` as a collection.

We can use this in our application like so:

```
User::find($id)->vehicles();
```

**Note**: You could return this as an **accessor** attribute by changing the function name to `setVehiclesAttribute()`. This will allow you to access the vehicle field like `User::find($id)->vehicle`.

Comment: Welcome @Mateo!